# Ask questions on understanding problems

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I would like to know whether there is a community on Stack where I am able to ask a question on understanding problems.

Let's say I am going through a documentation or I am reading a tutorial on a blog, but I don't understand it properly. Like when I have several lines of code I don't understand, which are obviously too complex for me and where I might need some help of explanation.

Comment: I think that this would be better asked on [Meta Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com/), but I'm reluctant to migrate as it's not very clear.

Comment: The first sentence seems a little vague, perhaps this question can be reworded a little.

Comment: Yes, it might be a little vague but English is not my mother tongue I am sorry. I tried to explain what I meant in the following sentences a bit more :/

Comment: If I understand what you are saying correctly, Stack Overflow would be the right site for that question. As long as it's a *specific* piece of code, or a specific concept (not "Teach me OOP", or "Explain the codebase of Linux", but rather "What does the author mean referring to encapsulation here?" and "How do these five lines of code work?") you should be fine.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129632/165773

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These type of questions belong to Stack Overflow, as long as you:

- Put relevant code in the question
- Describe precisely what you don't understand
- Make it very specific
- Make it relevant for others

If you can't meet these requirements, a question will be pretty much always off-topic for any Stack Exchange site. The only place you might get some luck then is in the Chat rooms.